# Is it possible to use .m4a files with Google Speech to Text API?

Tags: node.js, firebase, speech-recognition, google-cloud-speech

I recently filed an issue asking Google about this, but the answer is quite confusing.
The person who answered said that it is possible if you specify "MP3" as encoding.

I tried that and it did not work.

However the person at Google closed the issue. So I really do not know how to proceed.

https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/166478543

My understanding is that the encoding in my .m4a file is not MP3 and that the person who answered got this a bit wrong.

(I also got some nice advice not to use .m4a.
But this is not an option in my case since I am not producing the files.
I have no influence whatsoever over that. Unfortunately.)

Is there someone here who can clarify if Google Speech to Text API can handle .m4a? (I have added some tags to clarify the environment.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I was in your position, I would use https://www.npmjs.com/package/audiobuffer-to-wav to convert the M4A to WAV, then use the WAV file which google SR accepts easily.

Comment: Are you saying that this is something that can be used in Node.js in the context I pointed to with the tags?

Comment: Yup you can use that in node.js to take your M4A file and turn it into a WAV file. Then use the WAV file instead of an MP3, which google SR accepts just fine.

Comment: After staring at the code for some minutes I realize that AudioContext does the real job. From what version of Node.js is that available?

Comment: After looking around for some minutes I think that AudoContext is not supported in Node.js. Why do you think it is supported there?

Comment: But. This whole npm package looks like client side code. And since it is MIT licensed I can do what I want with it. The wav encoding looks like it could be rather fast. I will give it a try. (And if it is not fast enough converting it to RUST looks like a rather easy exercise in RUST. Wonder if anyone is interested in doing that?)

Comment: Hm. And the API is not really ready yet: https://github.com/WebAudio/web-audio-api/issues/1305

Comment: I just tested this on my cheap laptop and my cheap Android one mobile. It works and seems useable, at least for small audio files. 1 second for encoding by AudioContext and 1 second for creating the .wav file per minute.

Comment: But then comes this cross-origin (CORS) trouble which sometimes just spoils the whole idea with PWA: "Cannot capture from element with cross-origin data". :-(

Comment: @Leo sorry just saw this, hmm, if you are getting CORS that means they do not have CORS setup. You want to run that code server side in node.js backend, not client side.

Comment: Oh, it works. But I hoped to grab the audio from the audio element, but that is blocked. A bug, of course. Now I just have to figure out how to create the ArrayBuffer for the case when reading from a file. And just hey the pieces together. The boring part, when you already know. But it's nice to see it working later.